# What is the alternative of applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning in UIKit for SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to control low memory state in my SwiftUI app.
What is the alternative of applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning in UIKit for SwiftUI when you choose SwiftUI lifecycle?

I found didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification for Notification Center, but it is also implemented on UIKit, not on Foundation.

Or if there is no alternative, should I use UIKit lifecycle?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Combine publisher which detects `UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notifications.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let memoryWarningPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification)

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
            .onReceive(memoryWarningPublisher) { _ in
                print("memory warning")
            }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]